# Filter Between NSDates with NSPredicate

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

A simplified version of my coredata model looks like this
[image: Core Data Model]
I'm trying to filter a set of assets that meet the following criteria  "type"== "DIVIDEND_TYPE" and the "date" falls between "startDate" and "endDate".

My predicate looks like this

```
 NSPredicate *myPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                                @"ANY transactions.type == %@ AND ANY transactions.date >= %@ AND ANY transactions.date <= %@", DIVIDEND_TYPE, startDate, endDate];

NSSet *filteredSet = [self.portfolio.assets filteredSetUsingPredicate:myPredicate];
```

This predicate seems to respect the startDate and type, but not the endDate. The filteredSet always includes assets that contain transactions that have dates beyond the endDate.

What I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditions get tested independently for each ANY clause, so if an `Asset` has any transactions of the right type, and any transactions with date after startDate ,etc,  - but it could be a different transaction that meets each test.  Use SUBQUERY instead: it allows you to test several attributes of each transaction:

```
NSPredicate *myPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(transactions, $T, $T.type == %@ AND $T.date >= %@ AND $T.date <= %@).@count > 0", DIVIDEND_TYPE, startDate, endDate];
```